# Can Cassandra Compaction Lead To Timeouts?

Tags: cassandra, titan

I am using Titan `1.0.0` to bulk load a large amount of data (35M vertices) as quickly as possible into a single node instance of Cassandra. During this process a cleanup procedure triggers periodically which mutates some properties on `x` nodes, where `10000 < x <= 500000`. I ensure that each transaction only affects exactly 100 vertices.

Initially this process works but once my graph develops some super nodes I start to see the following exception:

```
com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: 
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.OperationTimeoutException: OperationTimeoutException: [host=172.18.02(172.18.0.2):9160, latency=4031(4031), attempts=1]TimedOutException(acknowledged_by:0, acknowledged_by_batchlog:true)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:171) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:153) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:119) ~[astyanax-core-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:352) ~[astyanax-core-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.executeOperation(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:517) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl.access$000(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:93) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1.execute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:137) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxStoreManager.mutateMany(AstyanaxStoreManager.java:389) ~[titan-cassandra-1.0.0.jar!/:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TimedOutException: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$atomic_batch_mutate_result$atomic_batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:29624) ~[cassandra-thrift-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$atomic_batch_mutate_result$atomic_batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:29592) ~[cassandra-thrift-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$atomic_batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:29526) ~[cassandra-thrift-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78) ~[libthrift-0.9.2.jar!/:0.9.2]
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_atomic_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1108) ~[cassandra-thrift-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.atomic_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1094) ~[cassandra-thrift-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1$1.internalExecute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:147) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftKeyspaceImpl$1$1.internalExecute(ThriftKeyspaceImpl.java:141) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60) ~[astyanax-thrift-3.8.0.jar!/:3.8.0]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

I have noticed that when this happens Cassandra is busy running large compaction jobs:

```
WARN  09:43:59 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:0000000000357200 (252188100 bytes)
WARN  09:47:03 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:6800000000365a80 (1417482764 bytes)
WARN  09:48:37 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:0000000000002480 (127497758 bytes)
WARN  09:51:58 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:6000000000376d00 (227606217 bytes)
WARN  09:54:35 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:d000000000002b00 (124082466 bytes)
WARN  09:58:24 Compacting large partition test/edgestore:6800000000354380 (172991088 bytes)
```

So the question is simple: Can Cassandra Compaction lead to the above timeouts and if so, what is the best approach for handling this ?

Comment: Try the alternative [compaction strategies](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_configure_compaction_t.html) and see if things improve?

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. I will try the different compaction strategies then. Can compaction actually cause Timeouts ?

Comment: I guess so. If your commit log is on the same disk hardware as your data, then the compaction can increase write latency to the commit log. Also, a write might trigger a flush of the memtables to SStable. If your SStables are being compacted the flush might have to wait? From the [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_write_path_c.html): "_If the data to be flushed exceeds the queue size, Cassandra blocks writes until the next flush succeeds._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Cassandra Compaction lead to the above timeouts and if so, what is the best approach for handling this ?

Yes definitely. The root cause may not be the compaction itself but because of saturated I/O bandwidth. Below is one **possible** chain of issue:

1. Heavy compaction
2. Disk I/O is not keeping up fast enough
3. Data are staying longer in memory
4. Data are promoted to JVM old generation
5. Stop-the-world garbage collection start to kick in
6. The node is detected as **down** by other node

The first thing to check is to grep for the keyword "GC" in your `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` and to monitor the I/O and CPU I/O wait using `dstat` tool

Also how much is the configure JVM Heap size?

Comment: Right now the JVM is about 8GB and I have checked the logs and I see that "GC" appears more and more as I load data. Any advice on how to resolve this ?

Comment: If there are more and more GC, it means that Cassandra does not flush data fast enough for the insertion rate. Describe your disk specs. Are they SSDs or spinning disks ?